# Displaying most popular/viewed articles - divided by time

Tags: php, mysql

i have a news website

On the home page i want to list the 4 most viewed articles in the last 7 days

i have a table, Articles: id, title, body, publishTime, viewCount...

i cant just display the top 4 in order of view count, as the longer it has been out, the generally more views it will have.
so i need to divide views by hours displayed

so my query needs to get all articles in last 168 hours, divide each view count by hours shown, then just show top 4

is it possible to do this with just commands, or do i need to create some kind of virtual table?

(using php & mysql)

thanks

Comment: Dividing `viewCount` by the time that has elapsed since `publishTime` will yield the article's *average rate of views* since its publication.  The articles with greatest such values *are not* the same as those that have been "*most viewed in the last 7 days*".  To obtain the latter, you would need to track (at very least) the number of views each article receives on each day.

Comment: For example, imagine an article that was published a year ago but which received 100k views over its first week (and nothing since); it would have a greater "average view rate" than an article that was published two weeks ago and has been viewed ten times in the past week.  Yet the latter article has been viewed more times in the last 7 days...

Comment: @eggyal hmmm, good point/things to think about. so are you sugeesting to divide views by days published? as that was my thinking, but i thought why not do it by hours to get a more accurate result.

Comment: @eggyal - above reply was to first comment - had not seen your second

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that **you would need to track (at very least) the number of views each article receives on each day.**  This cannot be achieved using your existing data or database structure.

Comment: @eggyal i see your point, but as im just doing it for just the last 7 days, that "initial 100k" effect matters less. for now, im happy just with views divided by time

Comment: But my point is, you wouldn't know whether the `viewCount` value of 100k relates to views from within the last 7 days or to views from last year.

Comment: @eggyal  ? dont understand - my query would somewhere contain "...WHERE publishdate < (today + 7days)" - so articles over a week old would never even come in to play

Comment: If you're happy to limit your query to articles that have been published in the past week, then surely you only need to sort by `viewCount` and ignore the amount of time that the article has been published?  Else your "most viewed" will be heavily biased towards the newest articles: imagine there is an article published one week ago with 150 views; and four articles published in the past hour each with 1 view.  By dividing by number of hours since publication, the four new articles will each have more than 1 view per hour; whereas the older article will have less than 0.9 views per hour.

Comment: @eggyal - in reply to last comment, yes- i figure that would be the best option, as its still fairer than just view counts, as that would just pretty much make it the 4 longest displayed articles

Comment: In that case, you're not after "*the 4 most viewed articles in the last 7 days*": you're after "*the 4 articles with the highest average view rate that have been published in the last 7 days*"... I will post an answer to that problem - please also edit your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per our discussion in the comments, it seems that you're not after "*the 4 most viewed articles in the last 7 days*" but rather "*the 4 articles with the highest average view rate that have been published in the last 7 days*".  This can be achieved as follows:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     Articles
WHERE    publishTime > CURRENT_TIME - INTERVAL 7 DAY
ORDER BY viewCount / (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publishTime)) DESC
LIMIT    4
```

Comment: perfect. thank you. i didnt know you could do a division inside a query. in the title i did use the word 'popular' which i feel is a close enough sentiment to what is trying to be achieved. but thank you.

Comment: @Lan: Sure, you can use an arithmetic expression in the `ORDER BY` clause - but beware that this can't be resolved using an index, so it will involve calculating the value of the expression for each article published in the past week and then performing a filesort over the results.  Depending on the number of articles published each week, this could become quite a cumbersome load for a query that is to be run on your homepage!

Comment: good point, but at the peak there may be 20 articles a day, times 7 = 140 articles - thats not too bad a load for a query, is it

Comment: @Lan: How many hits does the homepage receive?  If you're running this calc & filesort thousands of times every second, it's going to get very noticeable indeed.  You may wish to consider some way to cache the results, e.g. once per hour.

Comment: @Lan: Alternatively, you could add another (indexed) column `viewRate` to hold that quotient and update it every time `viewCount` is updated.

Comment: ahh yes, good point, i'll add a viewrate cloumn. cant believe i didnt think of that